# Parsing: He was sure he would leave behind in his community, should he die

Tags: conditional-constructions, syntax, free-relative-clauses

> Ever since Barry's funeral, Gavin had dwelled, with a sense of deep inadequacy, on the comparatively small gap that **[A] he was sure [B] he would leave behind in his community, should he die**. Looking at Mary, he wondered whether it would not be better to leave a huge hole in one person's heart. Had Barry not realized how Mary felt? Had he not realized how lucky he was? (The Casual Vacancy, J. K. Rowling)

1. What does ‘*leave behind*’ mean in the context? Is there a blank [gap] after *leave behind*, coindexed with ‘*comparatively small gap*’?
2. Are the he’s different: [A] Gavin, [B] Barry?
3. Is this clause, ‘*Should he die*,’ the complement of ‘*he was sure*’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ever since Barry's funeral, Gavin had dwelled, with a sense of deep inadequacy, on the comparatively small gap that [A] he was sure [B] he would leave behind in his community, should he die.

The phrase *should he die* is a conditional antecedent. It has the same funtion as an *if*-clause. We know this because the subject *he* and the modal verb *should* are inverted. "*Should he ...*"

"*Ever since Bary's funeral*" and "*with a sense of deep inadequacy*" are adjuncts. We don't need them to understand the main meaning of the sentence. Let's ignore them for the time being.

The sentence therefore means the same as:

- Gavin had dwelled on the comparatively small gap that he was sure he would leave behind in his community, if he died.

Both ocurrences of *he* refer to the same person, Gavin:

- Gavin had dwelled on the gap that Gavin was sure that Gavin would leave behind in his community if he died.

There is a relative clause in the sentence. Because of this there is an empty object position after "*leave*". It has the same indentity as the "*comparatively small gap*":

- Gavin dwelled on the comparatively gap<sub>(i)</sub> that [ he was sure that he would leave _____<sub>(i)</sub> behind in his community if he died ].

We can understand it like this:

- Gavin dwelled on the  gap that [ he was sure he would leave (it) behind in his community if he died ].

Comment: Thanks so much. Now I've got what Rowling says. She describes Gavin's unsatisfactory love life, domestically and socially. Maybe Gavin would be jealous of late Barry's comparatively larger gap left behind in his family and community.

Comment: @Listenever Exactly so! :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, "leave behind" refers to the "gap"

> He would leave a **gap** behind.

3. **"should he die"** is a condition.  Treat it the same as **"if he would die"**.  I.E.

> **If he would die**, he would leave a **gap** behind.

2. since **"should he die"** is a condition of **"he would leave behind a gap"**, and since Barry is already dead (we know he's dead because he had a funeral), It doesn't make sense for **He** to refer to Barry.  It refers to Gavin both times.

Comment: Do you like green eggs and ham?

Answer (score 2):

> Ever since Barry's funeral, Gavin had dwelled, with a sense of deep
>   inadequacy, on the comparatively small gap that [A] he was sure [B] he
>   would leave behind in his community, should he die.

Barry is already dead.  He has had a funeral.

Gavin dwelled ... on  = Gavin's mind was preoccupied with

Gavin dwelled on the ... small gap

On which gap?

on the gap (that) he was sure (that) he would leave behind in his community

Gavin in the antecedent for *he*, *he*, and *his* there.

Under what conditions would Gavin leave this gap?

If he should die.

He *would leave* the small gap behind if he *should die* (should he die).

The condition goes with "would leave".

Comment: I like this breakdown - it might be helpful to explain how "comparatively small" fits in as a comparison to the impact of Barry's death.